# How can I fix the tiny fonts problem in Audacity?

Tags: fonts, audacity

I'm trying to run Audacity under Kubuntu 20.04, but the font is unreadably tiny. The system fonts have no visible effect. How can I enlarge the fonts that Audacity and its help files it uses?

Comment: Does audacity have any font defaults in a /etc/X11/app-defaults file?

Comment: No font default sizes in app-defaults.